# Getting values before and after characters "-" in a String

Tags: javascript

I have the following string variable in Javascript;

var str = "12-134, 65-598, 100-210, 857-34, 3-21, 89-103".

I'd like to return all the values before and after "-" separately. That is before "-" ; "12, 65, 100, 857, 3, 89". And after "-"; 134, 598, 210, 34, 21, 103. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See JavaScript's `split()` method.  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp making yours `str.split("-");`

Comment: I will. Thanks Matthew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably split the values first using the commas and then split each value within that with the hyphen. Maybe something like this?

```
var firstArray[];
var secondArray[];
var strArray[] = str.split(",");
for (var i=0 ; i<strArray.length; i++){
   var strVal[] = strArray[i].split("-");
   firstArray.push(strVal[0]);
   secondArray.push(strVal[1]);
}
```