# Get value from a string before and after a special character - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters, trim

Hi I want to read values before and after special character in text of a variable.

The special character will always be the same e.g., '|' For example, my text will be stored as

```
var username = Username|Jackie;
var password = Password|myPass;
var temp = ""
```

After reading the, I would be carrying out a if-statement as follows

```
IF text BEFORE | == USERNAME
   temp == text AFTER |
ESLE IF text BEFORE ==  Password
   temp == text AFTER |
```

I hope I am making sense, if not, please let me know :)

I have been able to do this, but it only reads text after the special text and I want both after and before.

```
var myString = someVariableName.val().split("|").pop();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bf1L5e7y/1/

Comment: `let [BEFORE, AFTER] = someVariableName.val().split("|");`  `<-` [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: A working example: `var [before, after] = 'Username|Jackie'.split("|")`

Comment: @Ele Please could you given an working example in query, I am fairly new to web-development and might not be able to translate this into code (I think let is not part of jquery) - correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @KevinJantzer could you provide jsfildle in the answer so I can also accept it please :)

Comment: Also is this an array var [before, after]? and would I replace 'Username|Jackie' with variable name? How would I use/reference to before, after?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting values before and after characters "-" in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115754/getting-values-before-and-after-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: @HereticMonkey - the link you provide is outdated and verbose

Comment: @KevinJantzer Then put your answer in the duplicate. All you're doing by answering this one is spreading the answers across two questions. So when people search and find the duplicate, they won't get the benefit of your wisdom. Just trying to help your answer get more eyeballs by putting it on a question with more views, but if you want to be a jerk about it, that's cool too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one line using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

A working example

```js
var [before, after] = 'Username|Jackie'.split("|")

console.log(before)
console.log(after)
```

The above is the same as doing this:

```js
var pieces = 'Username|Jackie'.split("|")
var before = pieces[0]
var after = pieces[1]

console.log(before)
console.log(after)
```

Comment: If I have multiple variables e.g., username, password etc. would before and after be the same or do I need to use different variables like before1, after1, before2,after2, etc...

Comment: You can re-use the variable names, so long as you don't need to reference the "before/after" of both variables at the same time.

Comment: How do you mean with 1 liner? like this? 
var [a, b] = [10, 20];

Answer (score 1):

.split() will take a string and generate an array around the delimiter you define. ([String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split))
This means that running .split() on your strings will return an array of length 2 with your value in index 1.

```js
const username = "Username|Jackie";
const arr = username.split("|");
console.log(arr); // ["Username", "Jackie"];
```

You can access these values using index based array manipulation or the array destructuring notation. ([Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))

```js
const username = "Username|Jackie";

const arr = username.split("|");
console.log(arr); // ["Username", "Jackie"];
console.log(arr[0]); // "Username"
console.log(arr[1]); // "Jackie"

const [type, val] = username.split("|");
console.log(type); // "Username"
console.log(val); // "Jackie"
```