# Rest API Separating Data within a field

Tags: javascript, rest

I currently have a description field in my Rest API Get call that has two sets of data. It appears like this below.

```
"description": "Type_of_server;Owner:Yumma1",
```

I was wondering if there was any way I could separate the main description from the "owner" ID in the results of the description. The code for pulling the description is below. If you know of a change I could make to separate the data that'd be super helpful! Thank you!

```
description: vm.description,
```

Comment: We have no idea what is the description and what is the Requestor ID. Remember; we're just randos on the internet :). If the data are always separated by semicolons and colons, you can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to break the string into different parts...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get value from a string before and after a special character - Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273973/get-value-from-a-string-before-and-after-a-special-character-jquery)

Comment: Yes that definitely helps! Thanks for your response :)